# Yup validate condition based on other fields

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, yup

Imagine I have a form that has 3 input fields:

```
interface FormType {
  registerDate: boolean;
  fromDate: Date;
  toDate: Date;
}
```

When registerDate is true, both fromDate and toDate is required. Also, I need to validate that toDate is after fromDate.

I've tried something like this, by chaining 'when' conditions with Yup.

```
{
  registerDate: yup.boolean().required(),
  fromDate: yup.string()
    .when('registerDate', (registerDate) => {
      if (registerDate) {
        return yup.string().required('Required');
      }
    })
    .transform(dateTransformer),
  toDate: yup.string()
    .when('registerDate', (registerDate) => {
      if (registerDate) {
        return yup.string().required('Required');
      }
    })
    .when('fromDate', (fromDate) => {
       if (fromDate) {
         return yup.date().min(fromDate, 'To Date has to be before From Date');
       }
    })
    .transform(dateTransformer),
}
```

The Date transformer is a simple transformer for my date format with dayjs

```
const dateTransformer = (value: string): string => {
  return dayjs(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};
```

It looks like both .when functions gets triggered, but my transformer does not trigger, so I get a Yup.date object in my submit function. Any suggestions on how to solve this kind of cross validation?

Comment: If you put the transform() before the when does it trigger and work as you expect?

Comment: no.. Its looks like its the yup.date().min function that is acting up..